# Applying code in Wordpress functions.php to only one category

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to limit the following code that I've added to my functions.php file so that it only applies to a single wordpress category?

```
<?php remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

I tried this, but it didn't seem to work:

```
<?php if (in_category('work')) { remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); } ?>
```

I should also add that I solved this problem by placing the code directly in the specific category template, but I'd prefer to keep the filter in my functions file.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would need to add it to single.php instead of category template. Best way would be to add it to your header file so that it applies to all pages. I don't know why it doesn't work in functions.php

Comment: where r u triggering this? after init or before?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will want to hook into the `pre_get_posts` [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). It fires right after the query string is parsed. Some but not all of the conditionals are set up. You can test if in_category() is one of them, but I don't think it matters. Why? Glad you asked.

The hook is going to pass you the query object, which has the property `category_name`. All you have to do is check if it has your category and if so fire your filter.  Something like this:

```
function ns_function_name($wpq){
    if($wpq->category_name == 'work'){
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ns_function_name' );
```

This is totally untested. But since you seem to know what you are doing, it should be enough to put you on the right path.

Comment: Your code have a bug "Notice: Undefined property: WP_Query::$category_name "

Comment: The answer is more of an illustration of the pattern OP should use to accomplish his task. I did note that it is untested, and clearly other checks should first be made, such as is_set(). Without seeing your code, I can't really know what you are doing right or wrong. You might try creating a new question if you are having trouble with it. Also, according to WP docs, "pre_get_posts runs before WP_Query has been setup".

Answer (score 0):

Your functions.php is not aware of the current request like your index and category pages are. To make this code work in functions.php, you'll have to grab the raw server vars and parse through them to load up wp_query functionality that is relevant to the current url:

```
$url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$ID = url_to_postid($url[0]);
```

Once you have that ID you can do a query loop and trigger your filter based on the category.